# oc/kubectl patch replaces whole line

Tags: docker, openshift, kubectl

I am using oc patch with op to replace one string in deployment, following is the command:-

```
oc patch dc abc --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/image", "value": "ab-repository/" },{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/image", "value": "bc-repository/" }]'
```

what it is doing is it changes below:-

```
Before:- ab-repository/ab:1.0.0
After:- bc-repository/
```

what I want is this:-

```
Before:- ab-repository/ab:1.0.0
After:- bc-repository/ab:1.0.0
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Below is the YAML

```
apiVersion: apps.openshift.io/v1
kind: DeploymentConfig
metadata:
  name: ruleengine
  namespace: apps
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    name: ruleengine
  strategy:
    activeDeadlineSeconds: 21600
    resources: {}
    rollingParams:
      intervalSeconds: 1
      updatePeriodSeconds: 1
    type: Rolling
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        name: ruleengine
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: ab-repository/ab:1.0.0 ### containers should be provided in the form of an array
```

Comment: Could you also attach the example `yaml` file so its structure is clearly seen ?

Comment: I have attached YAML, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '[replace](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#page-6)' operation works like remove/add entire value:

> This operation is functionally identical to a "remove" operation for
> a value, followed immediately by an "add" operation at the same
> location with the replacement value.

There's no such JSON patch operation as replace value partially ([RFC6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902), [RFC7386](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7386))

You can get image like:

```
oc get dc ruleengine -o=jsonpath='{..image}'
```

Then manipulate the value with sed and use it in 'oc patch'